# Video Playback Distortion in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, video

I am not sure how to describe it, thus searching has turned up results that don't seem to mirror what I am experiencing.  Playback on Hulu, Netflix, and Youtube (The only sites I have tried) are all experiencing weird distortion fast moving scenes of shows or videos where the image has striations that are shown in a taken screenshot.  Does anyone know how to describe it so I can find some info on fixing it, or better yet a method of fixing it?  I have already turned off hardware acceleration in Chrome and that has not fixed the issue.

[image]

Comment: Try searching for "screen tearing" on this site and see if anything relevant comes up.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I did some more searching using screen tearing, and that is what I am experiencing.  It seems that most are having the problem running only in fullscreen, but mine occurs in both modes.  I am on a 2014 Razer Blade, with the up to date NVIDIA drivers.  These problems are happening on both the NVIDIA GTX 765M card, and the Intel card.